# Vertical LinearLayout with ImageButton: Problems with different screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 vertical linear layouts in one horizontal parent linear layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ...
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar... />        
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/imagebtn_layout">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/button_layout">
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I add 2 buttons programmatically to their views:
One into imagebtn_layout and the other one into button_layout with the parameters: (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT). The text of the button is set to 20.6f. The picture for the image button has 44x44 pixels.

The result looks fine on my Pixel 2 (1920x1080), but horrible e.g. on 2560x1440:
[image]

I'm not sure what's wrong. The result should be that the ImageButton and the normal button are on all screens at the same line.

Edit: Solved after using the solution from gmetax and setting  android:layout_height in the parent view to "wrap_content" and adapting font size of text button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the width of the image that you know and then let the other fill the empty space.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/imagebtn_layout">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/button_layout">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was fast and correct! Now there is no more overlapping. I also specified the heigth of the normal button and it seems fine now on all screens.

Comment: @scenox happy to have helped you